# Binding an object inside of an object literal's method (ES5)

Tags: javascript, object, binding, literals, ecmascript-5

I have two objects, Person and Person1, and I am trying to understand why I am unable to bind person1.getName to use a different methodName in the Person object.  If I take the code below and run it in the console I get an output of

Name: undefined undefined

Here is my code:

```
var Person = {
  firstname : "John",
  lastName : "Doe",
  getFullName : function() {
    console.log("Name : " + this.firstname + " " + this.lastName);
  }
};

var Person1 = {
  firstname : "Jane",
  lastName : "Doe",
  Person1.getName : Person.getFullName.bind(Person1)  
}

Person1.getName();
```

However, if I remove the method from the Person1 object literal and add it after the fact the method works correctly in the code below:

```
var Person = {
  firstname : "John",
  lastName : "Doe",
  getFullName : function() {
    console.log("Name : " + this.firstname + " " + this.lastName);
  }
};

var Person1 = {
  firstname : "Jane",
  lastName : "Doe"
}

Person1.getName = Person.getFullName.bind(Person1);  
Person1.getName();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var Person1` is hoisted, and `Person1` variable is defined but equal to `undefined` at the moment when `Person.getFullName.bind(Person1)` is evaluated.

Due to how `this` works, the method doesn't require binding (unless it's used separately from its context, e.g. as callback).

It should be:

```
var Person1 = {
  firstname : "Jane",
  lastName : "Doe",
  getName : Person.getFullName
}
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying.  I was reading how javascript is a late binding language and thought getFullName.bind(Person1) was evaluated at a much later time because of bind method.

Comment: `bind` is not syntactic feature but regular function (even though it's built-in) and it's evaluated accordingly. It performs early binding.

Answer (score 1):

1. In an object literal you can not reference to the variable name that the object will be assigned to.
2. `Person1.getName : Person.getFullName.bind(Person1)` is not the correct syntax to declare a method in an object literal. You are doing it correctly in `var Person`.

Your code has to be:

```
var Person1 = {
   firstname : "Jane",
   lastName : "Doe",
   getName : Person.getFullName  
}
```

Comment: *Your code has to be* - it contradicts (1), doesn't it?

Comment: @estus Why? You cannot access the variable Person1 in the assignment of the variable Person1, but you can access previous assigned variables. Please explain why this contradicts itself?

Comment: *You cannot access the variable Person1 in the assignment of the variable Person1* - but you do when you call `bind` with `Person1` argument. See my answer for the explanation.